# Turn off email notifications when outlook is set to "Out of Office"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook

I have an intranet application that sends emails to administrators. There are lots of emails generated each day and so I wanted to turn off email notifications automatically when they set their Outlook status to "Out Of Office".

Is this possible? The app was made using ASP.NET MVC 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to write a plugin of Outlook to add data in your application when they set their status to "Out of office". This is a tutorial on how to write Outlook plugins in C#

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2004/03/21/93712.aspx